# jquery or javascript classic to add http header infomation in the browser (permanent value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, header

I was wondering if it is possible to add http header information on a browser using jquery or a classic javascript in such a way that this added info will always available during http request like the "user-agent" sent in the server?

sorry on my wild imagination... ;)

Best regards,
- toni

Comment: Yup. Sounds exactly like what a cookie does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Cookie is limited. :) i can only get/set the value on a specified domain. I wish the value is available in any domain that the user enter on his browser. ;)

Comment: I found this article http://www.developertutorials.com/learn-ajax/custom-http-headers-2643.php. It almost answer my question but I want a value that is permanent ;)

Comment: You can only set cookies for your domain. You can only make http requests to your domain, so adding headers for another domain does not make sense. If you want to create a new header like 'User-Agent', create a browser plugin and ask your users to install it.

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery 1.5, there is a 'headers' option in the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method :

Try it this way :

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-My-Custom-Header':'value';
    },
    // ... Your other parameters in order
    // to define your request (url, method, etc.) ...
});
```

Comment: This does not achieve what the question asks (even without the clarification in the comments to the question which mean that this doesn't come anywhere near close to achieving what is desired).